# Terms Aggregations in multiple fields Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have several fields in ES like:

```
tank1
tank2
tank3
```

Every tankID can be in different fields depending on user choice. I wonder if I can count terms from multiple fields(tank1, tank2, tank3) and create graph in kibana 5?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "count" as your metrics aggregation and "filter" as your bucket aggregation and then use OR inside the filter for your multiple fields.